# Why did Ubuntu remove SpiderMonkey package?

Tags: package-management

I noticed Ubuntu didn't support SpiderMonkey since 10.04. I guess it may have something to do with license. Can You Tell Me The Reason Why?

Comment: Have a look at [rhino vs spidermonkey](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3563909/rhino-vs-spidermonkey)

Comment: @Mitch thanks for the pointer.  But that stackoverflow answer doesn't address the question here, of why SpiderMonkey was removed.  It just compares it with rhino.